# Problem in SVR using Python - Getting very low values while prediction

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I am using SVR for the prediction of rainfall using Python. I have taken 7 predictors (like x1, x2,...x7) and a predictand (i.e. rainfall, y). I have around 50 years training datasets of predictors & predictand, and 100 years testing data for predictors. I fitted SVR and then used 7 predictors (using 100 years data) to predict 100 years rainfall. The codes are executed correctly. But when I am seeing the predicted results of rainfall so I am getting very low values (the mean is around 10 and the max is 30) while the actual mean is around 70 and the maximum is 141. Please suggest me.
Here are my codes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Import data

X_hist = pd.read_csv('X.csv') # predictors-total 7
y_hist = pd.read_csv('y.csv') # predictand as a rainfall 
X_pred = pd.read_csv('X_predictors.csv') # test data of predictors- 7 

#Preprocessing
X_hist.head() 
y_hist.head() 
X_pred.head() 

#converted into np arrays
X_hist1=np.array(X_hist)
y_hist1=np.array(y_hist)
X_pred1=np.array(X_pred)

#changed the variable name for my reference
X_train=X_hist1
X_test=X_pred1
y_train=y_hist1


#Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x=StandardScaler()
sc_y=StandardScaler()
x =sc_x.fit_transform(X_train)
y =sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)

# Training SVR to dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(x,y)

#Predict using Regression Model 
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_x.transform(np.array(X_test))))

pred1=pd.DataFrame(y_pred)
pred1.to_csv("results.csv")
```

Comment: One thing that comes into mind is that your model might be overfit because you didn't use cross-validation. Therefore, I would suggest grid searching on some of the hyperparameters, such as `C` and `epsilon`.

Comment: thanks. could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: i tried with these parameters but the results are same, no improvement

Comment: Here are a couple links from the sklearn documentation on [hyperparameter search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) and [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation).  You'll most likely be using sklearn's [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) which does both the hyperparam tuning and cross validation.

Comment: Two things to try would be not scaling your `y` values and also trying a linear kernel rather than rbf.

Comment: thanks 2 ncfirth, i tried with linear and sigmoid too but there is no improvement, can you more elaborate "not scaling your y values"?

Comment: @VishalSingh He meant that your data should be scaled properly. Please, read [Tips on Practical Use](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use) carefully. The first error you made is that you scaled train vector independently. "the same scaling must be applied to the test vector to obtain meaningful results." The second is - did you check what you've obtained after using StandardScaler? Maybe you should use another Scaler or Normalizer.